# Update the field in the table with the sequence number of the unique value of other field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, distinct

I have a table "my_table" with two fields: "name" and "name_id". The field "name_id" is a number.

```
name| name_id
----+---------
foo | NULL
foo | NULL
bar | NULL
bar | NULL
bar | NULL
```

I need to update the "name_id" field with the sequence number of the unique value of the "name" field, so the result table looks like this:

```
name| name_id
----+---------
foo | 1
foo | 1
bar | 2
bar | 2
bar | 2
```

I wrote a mini program for MySQL:

```
SET @counter := 0;
UPDATE    
    (
        SELECT `name`, (@counter := @counter + 1) AS `newId`
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT `name`
                FROM `my_table`
                ORDER BY `name`       
            ) AS `temp`
    ) AS `src` RIGHT JOIN `my_table` AS `dest` ON `dest`.`name` = `src`.`name`
SET`dest`.`name_id` = `src`.`newId`;
```

Is this solution correct? Are where better solutions to accomplish this task?

Comment: which version of mysql do you have?

Comment: @Radim Bača the version of mysql is: 5.7.19

Comment: then you should upgrade to 8.0 :) and until then use Gordon's solution

Comment: @Radim Bača I would like to see solutions for any version of MySQL and also for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use variables:

```
set @rn := 0;
set @n := '';

update my_table
    set name_id = (@rn := if(@n = name, @rn,
                             if(@n := name, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                            )
                  )
   order by name;
```